# C# addXmlDefinition method

Tags: c#, xml

I have this methods that take in a xml file and add `XDeclaration` for utf-8.  I want to optimize the code because it need to `XDocument.Parse` and then `XDeclaration`. It also needs to `XDocument.save`. Any help would be great.

```
    private static string addXmlDefinition(string xmlContent)
    {
        string xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(xmlContent));
        var wr = new StringWriter();
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        xdoc.Declaration = new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null);
        xdoc.Save(wr);
        return wr.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you simply do this?

```
private static readonly string declaration = new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null).ToString();
private static string addXmlDefinition(string xmlContent)
  => string.Join(Environment.NewLine, new [] { declaration, xmlContent });
```

- Define the XML Declaration only once and reuse it
- Concat the declaration string and the content

  - Use new line as a delimiter between them

Answer (score 2):

1. `addXmlDefinition`: Method names should be PascalCased
2. `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(xmlContent));`: at best this does nothing, [at worst this mangles any character not representable in the default encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.default?view=net-7.0#:%7E:text=using%20the%20default%20encoding%20is%20not%20recommended)
3. Specifying the encoding in the `XDeclaration` does nothing when writing to a `StringWriter`, a string in .NET is UTF-16 and that will be reflected in the declaration. Has the output of the method been verified?